# Swift in terminal invalid UTF-8 found in source file

Tags: swift2

In swift 2.1 and Xcode 7.1.1

I have the code below which when run in the terminal, it produces the next block of output.

```
import Foundation
let oldName = "eleven"
let newName = "twelve"
let baseName = "/Users/empl1/Documents/abc/"
let ignorFile: Set = ["png", "jpg"]

let fm = NSFileManager()
let dirEnum = fm.enumeratorAtPath(baseName + oldName)
while let file = dirEnum?.nextObject() {
}
```

Here is what I see in the terminal:

```html
FredMac:Documents empl1$ swiftc copier.swift
FredMac:Documents empl1$ swift copier
copier:1:1: error: invalid UTF-8 found in source file
?????@   ? H__PAGEZEROx__TEXT__text__TEXT?
copier:1:2: error: invalid UTF-8 found in source file
?????@   ? H__PAGEZEROx__TEXT__text__TEXT?
copier:1:3: error: invalid UTF-8 found in source file
?????@   ? H__PAGEZEROx__TEXT__text__TEXT?
copier:1:4: error: input files must be encoded as UTF-8 instead of UTF-16
?????@   ? H__PAGEZEROx__TEXT__text__TEXT?
FredMac:Documents empl1$
```

How is this problem fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your source file is not in UTF8 encoding. Or if you copy & paste source from somewhere, there can be some hidden characters.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you should open terminal in the same directory as your source file, then

you either have to type `swift ./copier.swift` to run and interpret your source file immediately, without an exececutable emitted,

or `swiftc ./copier.swift` then  `./copier` to compile your source and run emitted `./copier` executable.